# Объявление переменной как ссылки на адрес

Tags: c++, mod

Предыстория: пишу мод на игру который меняет кое-какие значения. И тут я понимаю: мне нужно объявить переменную, что бы там было не число, а ссылка на игровой адрес, для последующего его редактирования.

Вопрос: Как мне объявить такую переменную-ссылку?

Мои попытки: пытался объявить так:
`DWORD Name = 0x9018C4;`
Но таким образом я просто помещаю значение в Name.
Еще была такая попытка:
`DWORD Name 0x9018C4 = 0.00005;`
Но тут уже просто синтаксическая ошибка.

Если что: тип данных адреса в игре foat

Comment: DWORD* pName = reinterpret_cast<DWORD*>(0x9018C4); *pName = ...

Comment: И еще один вопрос: если тип данных у адреса float, то я так же должен писать DWORD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Именно *ссылку* (не указатель) и именно с использованием *значения-адреса*?

```
Тип & имя = *(Тип*)адрес.
```

Ну, или (формально корректнее, по сути то же самое)

```
Тип & имя = *reinterpret_cast<Тип*>(адрес).
```

Например,

```
float& f = *(float*)0x004567;
```

Comment: На сколько я понял что если я подклбчусь к процессу через handle, выполню этот код
 float& name = *reinterpret_cast<float*>(0x9386F4), а потом *name = 4000;, у меня произойдет байт патчинг по этому адресу. Я правильно понял?

Comment: Если вы все верно сделали, все разрешения получили и т.д. — в этом хакинге я не так силен — то присваивать надо будет просто как `name = 4000;` (мы же работаем со ссылкой, а не с указателем).